# Как убрать непонятные пробелы вначале строки в item recyclerview?

Tags: android, recyclerview

У меня есть список с адаптером, и с таким элементом:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="90dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:singleLine="true"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="250dp"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="30dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/address"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:singleLine="true" />


        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/company"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:singleLine="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Данные в список тянуться с ответа сервера, ответ приходит в json. Странная проблема - в некоторых элементах замечено появление пробела в строке отвечающей за заголовок (title). Уже проверял по-всякому:

1. Смотрел на то что приходит с сервера - все нормально.
2. Проверял наличие пробела вначале строк - ничего нет.
3. Смотрел в бд откуда тянется инфа сервером - пробелов нет.

вот например:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробел появляется не в каждом элементе, а в некоторых, и визуально это очень некрасиво. Вроде пробелов нет, но они отображаются. Менял разметку - не помогло. В итоге у меня не получилось найти проблему. Вероятнее всего ошибка где-то в разметке, но не могу понять где именно.

Comment: Посмотреть бы на заголовки с пробелом и без. Там точно пробел, а не выравнивание, например?

Comment: @Эникейщик, мне кажется там точно не выравнивание - обновил вопрос.

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, у вас слева и справа `margin` в `RelativeLayout` в `CardView`.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, мне их убрать нужно чтобы все нормально отображалось? потому что без них не очень изменилась ситуация

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, да, нужно убрать. Странно, что не поменялось. Вообще, у вас там неправильно то, что несколько детей у `CardView` - должен быть только один

Comment: Мнтго лэйаутов как то, попробуйте один Constraint. Margin start тоже может мешать ну и паддингов много можно общим заменить. Даже один linnear воткнуть вместт всех этих и станет понятно.

Comment: Для таких целей есть Layout Inspector в студии, там все будет написано.